# Caculating Least Significant Bit in little endian and big endian

Tags: memory

From what I've researched, Little Endian stores the Least Significant Byte in the smallest memory address while Big Endian stores the Largest Significant Byte in the smallest memory address.

However, I don't understand how to calculate and compare the significant bytes.

For instance, from this [site](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html) , the image below shows how the 4  bytes, 90, AB, 12, CD are stored in memory addresses in Little Endian format.

[image: Little Endian]

How do I compare which byte is larger among the 4 ? I converted all to hex values first and then compare based on its decimal values, but it doesn't appear to work this way.

205 > 18, however CD is stored in the smallest memory address.. so.. I am wrong.

Any clarification is appreciated.

```
Treating CD as a hex value, with a decimal value of 205.
Treating 12 as a hex value, with a decimal value of 18.
Treating AB as a hex value, with a decimal value of 171.
Treating 90 as a hex value, with a decimal value of 144.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the web page that you link to contains a very confusing description of endianness!

The actual value of the individual bytes in the word has no relevance on where they are stored in memory, only their position as part of the whole 4 byte word.

Endianness only applies to multiple byte words. In your case, you have a 4 byte word as follows:

```
Decimal      Hex           Binary
2427130573   90 AB 12 CD   10010000 10101011 00010010 11001101
```

This is the big-endian representation, where the most significant byte (`0x90`) is stored first in memory, or in the lowest memory address.

In little-endian representation, the bytes are simply reversed in memory as follows:

```
Decimal      Hex           Binary
2427130573   CD 12 AB 90   11001101 00010010 10101011 10010000
```

Now the least significant byte (`0xCD`) is stored first in memory, or in the lowest memory address.

You see that the actual values of the bytes involved do not determine their location in memory, only their position in the whole word.

The concept of endianness goes back to CPU architecture as is then described int the article that you link to and there are advantages and disadvantages to both methods.

The most natural way for humans to think of numbers is in terms of big-endianness because this is how we treat decimal numbers. In your case, the decimal number `2427130573` could be said to be written in big-endian notation, i.e. the most significant digit (`2`) is written first with significance decreasing as you go right (i.e. changing the value of the leftmost digit has most significance on the value of the number). The number could equally be written left to right as `3750317242` with the least significant digit first, as long as you know to read it that way (EDIT: incidentally this is why unicode files should have a Byte Order Mark (BOM) stored in the first 2 bytes of the file so that the operating system knows how to interpret the file.)

However, for computers to perform calculations it is often most efficient to have the least significant byte stored first. I think that the arguments for big vs little endianness are a topic of another discussion and there are many sources for this online!

I hope that this helps to clarify somewhat!